# how to set datagrid numberbox prefix onchange combobox

Tags: datagrid, combobox, editor, jquery-easyui

I am using datagrid with inline editor which have validatebox, numberbox, and combobox. What I am try to do is when I select the combobox, I need to set numberbox prefix as currency symbol as I want. If I want to set the value to the numberbox, usually write like this:

```
var ed8 = $("#dg").datagrid("getEditor", {index:idx, field:'cost'});
$(ed8.target).numberbox('setValue',value);
```

but I am stack on case how to change/set the property "**prefix**" of numberbox. 
One more thing that I want to ask, Is that possible to set multiple prefix in one field (one row one prefix) of datagrid?

Comment: I try to get the options with `$(ed8.target).numberbox('options')` but got result `[object object]`. I don't know how to go far with it. I have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution by put the code like this.

```
var ed8 = $("#dg").datagrid("getEditor", {index:idx, field:'cost'});
var opts = $(ed8.target).numberbox('options');
opts.prefix = '$';
```

It is possible to set multiple prefix on a field

hope this can help others.